# How to put drawable in the middle of textView on android java

Tags: java, android

I can't find information on how to draw image in the middle of texview using drawable. Below Images on how the app looks like atht he moment

[image: knight not int the middle]  [image]

When the knight should be in the middle of box (textView). I have created my textviews dynamicly with loops so accessing XML file is not possible. I am using
`textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(ic_horsey, 0, 0, 0 )` to draw the image.

Comment: Without any code this is pretty difficult to answer. I would take a look at [ask] and how to produce a [mre].

Comment: To me it appears like each square should be a `FrameLayout`, and this FrameLayout contains an `ImageView` with `scaleType="center"` to show the drawable, as well as a `TextView` showing the row/column label at the top left.  Not clear why you're using a `TextView` with drawable

Comment: The `TextView` shouldn't take the entire area of the square, it'd be only on top left corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` are not used to display Drawables. You have to use an `ImageView` for that.

Regarding your screenshot, a `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView` for the letter and an `ImageView` for the chess piece will do the job to represent a chess cell